Spring Data MongoDB + SPEL aggregation issue
I have an aggregation in a Spring Data MongoDB repository, using @Aggregation annotation. Method has optional parameters, so I use SPEL to check input for nullability.
My question is: what is wrong with this expression?
"?#{ [10] == null ? {$expr: {$literal: true}} : {$or: [{'accountNumber': {$regex: [10]}}, {'target.properties.NAME': {$regex: [10]}} ]}}"

Getting this error:
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [ [10] == null ? {$expr: {$literal: true}} : {$or: [{'accountNumber': {$regex: '[10]'}},{'target.properties.NAME': {$regex: '[10]'}} ]}] @86: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'rsquare(])' but was 'comma(,)'

I checked several times, and all the paranthesses and other stuff is fine.
For example, from the same aggregation, this expression is parsed well:
"?#{ [8] == null ? {$expr: {$literal: true}} : {'_id': { $in: [8] } } }"

Any ideas?
Tried to play with spaces, used ?10 instead of [10], but no luck

Can you please share the complete code (to reproduce it)?

Sorry, I cannot, as it is a project under NDA. Only partial code can be shared, without big context

I mean @Aggregation method complete definition.
